# How to deploy RPM repodata correctly to Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory, rpm

**How can I deploy repodata that matches the below RPM repo-structure in Artifactory?**

I have an RPM repo in Artifactory as follows:

```
rpm-local/  
     {productName}/  
             {version}/  
                   {arch}/  
                       rpm-file1.rpm
                       rpm-file2.rpm
                       rpm-file3.rpm
```

And I deploy RPMs using curl:

```
curl -u "user:pass" -X PUT http://arti:8081/artifactory/rpm-local/{productName}/{version}/{arch} -T rpm-fileX.rpm
```

Only problem is yum doesn't find these RPM packages after a `yum clean all` and `yum update`.
**I don't know how to generate and deploy repodata for my repo-structure above.**

Can someone help with deploying repodata that matches the above repo-structure so that Artifactory will know where to look for these RPM packages?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I know nothing about artifactory. I'm taking that out of the equation.

If what you are showing is a standard filesystem, all you need to do is change to the directory with the RPMs in them (on the server) and type `createrepo -v` - this will create a `yum` repo. Then you will need to create a `yum.repo` file pointing to the HTTP server - see https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-configuring_yum_and_yum_repositories